# Find how many adjacent zeros in given list like this [100,1010,1001,1111,10100]

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, printing, count

I have tried this

```
list1=[100,1010,1001,1111,10100]
print(list1.count(00))
```

I got this

```
0
```

Expected Output:

```
3
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try:

```
list1 = [100,1010,1001,1111,10100]
print("".join(str(x) for x in list1).count("00"))
```

Prints: `3`

Comment: @mozway has a better solution, but this one may be easier to understand at a glance

Comment: This solution is a bit risky, it works because numbers cannot start with 0 in python, but if you were to search for `11` you would have side effects of counting 1s from two separate numbers. Also if you have `10000` you will count the number twice (but not sure if this is expected) ;)

Answer (score 2):

list.count(00) will only give you the number of occurrences of the value '00' in the list.
To look for the characters 00 within each list item you will need to iterate through the list and look at each item.
Easiest check would be to convert the value to a string and then check for the double 00 characters within that

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you could filter and count:

```
count = sum(1 for e in list1 if '00' in str(e))
```

output: `3`

Or, if a number like `10000` should count for 2 occurrences of `00`:

```
count = sum(str(e).count('00') for e in list1)
```